# What is wrong in my mex file? input/output definition?

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I am trying to run my mex function which I've written in c++ in VS. It compiles successfully in MATLAB but returns the wrong values. I'm pretty much sure, I'm not reading the 16-by-21 input matrix gammas. Can anybody see what is wrong here?

```
void fun(double gammas[], int num1, int num2, int length, double a[])
{
...
}

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs, int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs)
{
double *gammas, *a;
int num1, num2, length;
size_t mrows, mcols;
mrows = 4; mcols = 21;
length = 21;
plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix((mSize)mrows, (mwSize)ncols, mxREAL);
gammas = mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
num1 = (int)*mxGetPr(prhs[1]);
num2 = (int)*mxGetPr(prhs[2]);
a = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);

fun(gammas, num1, num2, length, a);
}
```

I get correct "a" when I call "fun" within a "main" instead of "mex" function in VS and manually provide the input gammas. I receive wrong "a" when I call the resulted mex file in my MATLAB code.

Comment: Can you show the signature of `fun()`? Is `a` supposed to be where the result is stored?

Comment: Judging by the variable names, I'd assume you want the result to be pointed at by `plhs` (I read it as "pointer to the left-hand-side"). In that case, casting the left hand side value as an integer and then passing that integer to another function will not save the result into `plhs`.

Comment: @Praetorian Yes "a" is the output/result.

Comment: @AustinMullins Sorry, that was my typo. I corrected it.

Comment: Doesn't your latest edit (`a = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);`) fix your problem?

Comment: @Praetorian, No that was my typo here not in the code itself.

Comment: Then you're going to have to show what you do inside of `fun()` and what the expected and actual results are.

Comment: Is result not just transpose of what you want or something like that ? Careful that linear storage is [column-major](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) for matlab while c/c++ is [row-major](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) ... maybe you mixed both ?

Comment: Is by the way `gammas` a matrix or a vector ?

Comment: @Praetorian, fun is a 200-lines code...both expected and actual results are double-valued 4-by-21 matrices. They are not transpose of each other. They are different.

Comment: @CitizenInsane  gammas is a 16-by-21 matrix. AND YES, I passed the transposed gammas to the same mex and it returned the correct result. Thank you CitizenInsane!

Comment: @CitizenInsane  Might as well post an answer.  You saw the issue first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suspected in comments to your question issue is due to how matlab and c/c++ order array elements for linear storage as 1D array in memory. Matlab uses [column-major](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) order while C/C++ uses [row-major](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order).

I would not advice you to do permutation prior to call mex-function but rather do the permutation inside the mex function. Either as suggested by @chappjc by call to `permute` with `mexCallMatlab` or by call to [`mxCalcSingleSubscript`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxcalcsinglesubscript.html) which returns matlab's linear index from coordinates (whatever the number of dimensions).

**Side note**: Need confirmation and find back great article I read about that, but matlab uses column-major ordering because it's more appropriate for matrix multiplication (creates less page-defaults when accessing memory cache, and is thus faster). Again **need confirmation** ... but at least this organisation is better suited for access by columns rather than by rows ...

**Edit**

Btw, some simple code (C#) to obtain coordinates from maltab's zero based linear index (reverse of [`mxCalcSingleSubscript`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxcalcsinglesubscript.html)):

```
private static int[] getCoordinatesFromMatlabLinearIndex(int index, int[] arrayDims)
{
    var ret = new int[count];            
    var count = arrayDims.Length;
    for (var k = 0; k < count; k++)
    {
       index = Math.DivRem(index, arrayDims[k], out ret[k]);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Good answer. +1 Thanks for calling out my suggestion.  I've linked to your answer instead of your comment now.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to inputting a transposed matrix to address the row/column-major discrepancy that [CitizenInsane pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28616392/2778484), you can have the transpose handled inside the MEX file.  Use a helper C++ function.  You can either write a loop to copy elements, or simply call `permute` via `mexCallMATLAB`.  Something like the following:

```
int permute2DMATtoC(mxArray*& matPermuted, const mxArray* mat)
{
    mxAssert(mxGetNumberOfDimensions(mat)<=3, "Requires 2D or 3D matrix.");

    mxArray *permuteRHSArgs[2];
    permuteRHSArgs[0] = const_cast<mxArray*>(mat);
    permuteRHSArgs[1] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,3,mxREAL);

    mxGetPr(permuteRHSArgs[1])[0] = 2;
    mxGetPr(permuteRHSArgs[1])[1] = 1;
    mxGetPr(permuteRHSArgs[1])[2] = 3; // supports 2D and 3D

    return mexCallMATLAB(1, &matPermuted, 2, permuteRHSArgs, "permute");
}
```

Use:

```
mxArray *matPermuted;
permute2DMATtoC(matPermuted, prhs[0]); // matPermuted is MATLAB-managed
double *gammas = (double*)mxGetData(matPermuted);
```

NOTE: Since `matPermuted` is manage by MATLAB, you don't need to explicitly destroy it to reclaim resources, but when you are done you can do this if you want:

```
mxDestroyArray(matPermuted);
```

For RGB, it may be necessary to convert pixel order (RGB-RGB-RGB-...) to planar order (RRRR...-GGGG...-BBBB...).